# .getElements() occasionally grabbing a Number?

Tags: javascript, mootools

Relevent jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/julianlam/eLs9E/

For some reason, given the dataset shown in the fiddle, when I try to grab all of the elements with the `data-interest-id` property, among the seven `li` elements, I get the Number "7" as well.

The two are related, as if I add another `li` element, the number is "8".

Any particular reason this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object returned from .getElements, in addition to its results, includes a length property.

When use the Object.each() function you iterate through all the properties. For example: If you change the .each to

```
Object.each(meh, function(element, key) {
    console.log(element+"-"+key);
});
```

You'll see that the console.log() within the each() function will show "length" as its key whereas the rest will have an index.

Comment: For those who got here via Google (who knows...). I worked around this by calling .each() on the same line as `.getElements()`. I am unsure as to whether `.each()` is deprecated (or soon to be), so caveat emptor.

Comment: `$('myElement').getElements('li').each(function() { // ... });`

Comment: classic Wtf! I migrated to Jquery and no problem at all:
  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/alonisser/mbqbA/

Comment: It is because you assume `getElements` returns an Object. It does not, it returns an Elements (type) collection, which is based on Array. Arrays in javascript are actually not real, they are objects with array like properties like `.length`. This allows you to call Objects methods with bad results as well as for .. in obj. Just read up on Elements.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, Dimitar. I did try `Array.each`, but that did not work either. However, I do get the gist of your comment in that ELements !== Array